# How to preload data before moving to another VC

Tags: swift, closures

I have a method that reads some data from a database and returns it in a closure, for example:

```
 DatabaseManager.readUser(withUserID: "Bob") { (user, error)
        MySingleton.shared.user = user
 }
```

I have a home VC which is my landing page, and a "user" VC that a user can navigate to. My user VC needs to display the data read from the database, in this case `MySingleton.shared.user`.

**My problem**:

I am currently trying to load the user's data on a background thread in my home VC, so by the time the user navigates to the user VC, the data can be displayed. However, if the user navigates to the user VC too fast, before the data was read, my app crashes because `MySingleton.shared.user` is nil, as expected.

My other option would be to load the data in `viewDidLoad()` in my user VC and display it after it was set in the closure. But this might cause there to be a kind of blank screen between the time the VC loads, and the time the data was read.

What is the best option here for a seamless user experience? Is there a way I can try to preload it in my home VC, and if its still not set by the time I navigate, wait until it is before displaying the user data?

Comment: Check if its nil -> show indicator that its downloading and on completion go to the other vc?

Comment: Where am I checking if it's nil, in the user vc?

Comment: I would get user data only upon a user click. Inside the click action start the activityIndicator and read the user data then inside your readUser `completion` handler stop the activiityIndicator and navigate to the user VC by passing data.

Comment: @Matt.kaaj Ok so you're saying only start the loading when they start navigating aka when the user presses the button to go to the user VC?

Comment: I'd agree with Matt.kaaj, fetch the data at a convenient point in the home VC and then you might have a property in the user VC that holds the fetched data for example. Once you have populated this only then move to the user VC.

Comment: @Brejuro Correct. You only request to get data either over the network or phone's DB, when there is a demand for that otherwise you are using the resources if a user never clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start data loading when the screen is opened you can proceed in the following way:

1. On button tap check that you data is loaded. If yes - open the next screen, if no - set a flag (for instance `openScreenOnDataLoad = true`) and display a progress indicator.
2. In your closure when the data load is finished check that flag and open the next screen if the flag is set.

If you are initiating the data load in some other place/class you can use notification to inform other parts of the program that the data was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

My general advice in these type of cases:

When Moving to a new ViewController, **any required dependancies should be injected at the time of initialization/segue**, and **everything else should be handled internally** during the ViewController's life cycle.

This makes the requirements for showing the ViewController clear, minimizes state complexity, and increases modularity.

In your case that means either the HomeVC needs to load the date (preferably indicating loading somewhere in the UI) and send it to the UserVC when it's made, or the UserVC will need to load the data and handle any loading UI there.

Personally I would prefer the second option minimize dependencies, simplifying navigating from anywhere else.

As an aside, if you're sure you want to use a singleton like that it's generally a good idea to handle the singleton management (creation, destruction) in the Model, and (at most) only *access* it from your ViewControllers